# CAN Controller DLL with Java Application. Unable to open CAN port

Tags: dll, java-native-interface, jna, can-bus

I am creating a Java application that controls a Controller Area Network (CAN) controller via a vendor-supplied **can.dll** file.

**can.dll** contains a function **bool openPort(DWORD memAddr)** that allows the application to establish connection with the CAN controller.

I wrote a C++ test application, loaded **can.dll** via LoadLibrary and found this function to be working as it should, i.e. it returns true.

However, in my Java application, calling this via JNI or JNA returns false.

I hope someone can help me with this problem as I have been trying to fix this problem for more than a week.

Thanks :)
JL

Comment: You can't call C++ functions using JNA, have you marked it appropriately as `extern "C"` in your **C++** code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at sockets as an alternative or other IPC solutions.